# How to draw a molecule using chemfig without attaching ring substituents to a specific position?

Tags: chemfig

I'm trying to draw a molecule using chemfig in a way which is shown in the following picture:

[image]

The side-rings are not supposed to be attached to a specific atom, to clarify that this substance is an isomeric mixture. Is it possible to accomplish something like this using chemfig?

I'm using the following code to draw one of the isomers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(---(--[:-30]*6(----(--[:-30]*6(--------))-(-)-))---)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 6):

all in one solution

```
\chemfig{*6(----
    (-[2])
    (-[:240,1.2,,,draw=none]-[:150]-[:210]*6(------))
    (-[:300,1.2,,,draw=none]-[:30]-[:330]*6(------))
    --)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can separate this into 3 pieces and overlap them by adding negative space between them. Of course the spacing and height of the raised portion can be adjusted to your liking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{*6(---(--[:-30])---)}
\hspace{-.3cm}\raisebox{.5 cm}{\chemfig{*6(----(-[:90])--)}}
\hspace{-.3cm}\chemfig{*6(-----([:-150]-[:150]-)-)}

\end{document}
```